# Photoshop temp files

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]

temp files are taking up all my free space.If i open a 250MB file it creates a temp of approx.2GB.and these files making my photo shop damn slow,how to stop PS making such big temp files?? every time i do delete it manually but it makes my photoshop more horrible all setting changed automatically after every delete..

please help

Answer (score 1):

Koiyu is right - you should probably shoot this over to Super User. In the meantime, you might try moving your primary scratch disk to a different hard drive. Go to Preferences -> Performance and select a different scratch disk. A firewire or USB 2.0 external hard drive should work fine. You can also address your Memory usage in that same tab.